# How to autofill Google form with random answears using JS

Tags: javascript, forms, google-forms, autofill

I want to randomly fill a 100 google forms using JS. Is any way to do it?
There is [example google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1zecX-Fr_tg6psFSgr7eIdGrEsJS33isEa4EQbL0OfyA/).
I couldn't find anything on stackoverflow or web, only python or java solutions. But I want to do it in javascript if it is possible of course.

Comment: You can use a browser extension like [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) or [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) to run a script of yours automatically on the page. Then, you just need to write a script which fills the form, submits it, and does that over and over. But... maybe Google will block you, seeing you're not a human and are spamming, which is great

Comment: @blex but how can i do that, google doesnt have any id in any field, i have only jscontroller which seems to be some kind of ID but is it id for real ? I don't know how to call getDocumentById when i dont have any id

Comment: Another problem is that, when i have more than 1 radio field or more than 1 input etc how can i chose which is what. Because i can only refer by id or by tag, but there is a lot divs . To be honest there are only divs, nothing more

Comment: You won't be able to use `getElementById` here, of course. But `querySelector` will help you. I successfully made a dirty script to fill the form you provided as an example _(you may see some answers)_. I'll try to clean it up and write an answer

Comment: @blex Yeah i can see, you made like 40 answears. If you will be so kind and give me that dirty script :D 
My form is more complicated than this one , but i think that when i see how it really works i can write something like this on my own using your template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a **dirty** script, which could be a starting point. It **only** works with the specific form you provided as an example. It uses `document.querySelector` to target the form elements.

As soon as you'll open the form, it will fill it, submit it, go back to it, submit it, over and over.

To use it:

- Install the [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) extension in Google Chrome
- Click on the icon that appeared in your browser, select "Dashboard"
- Create a new script, and replace all the content with the code below
- Ctrl + S to save
- Open the form in a tab and watch it do the work

Code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         GoogleForm Spammer
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Spam a Google Form
// @author       You
// @match        https://docs.google.com/forms/*
// @grant        unsafeWindow
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/forms/d') === 0) { // If we're on the form page
      submitRandomForm();
    } else if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/forms/u') === 0) { // If we're on the "submitted" page
      goBackToForm();
    }

    function submitRandomForm() {
      // Size
      var radios     = document.querySelectorAll(".appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupRadioButtonContainer"),
          radioIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * radios.length);
      radios[radioIndex].click();

      // Print
      var checkboxes    = document.querySelectorAll(".appsMaterialWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckbox"),
          checkboxIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * checkboxes.length);
      checkboxes[checkboxIndex].click();

      // Age (between 16 and 45)
      var age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 16;
      document.querySelector(".quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput").value = age;

      // Submit
      document.querySelector(".freebirdFormviewerViewCenteredContent .appsMaterialWizButtonPaperbuttonLabel").click();
    }

    function goBackToForm() {
      window.location.href = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd7GueJGytOiQpkhQzo_dCU0oWwbk3L1htKblBO1m14VHSpHw/viewform';
    }
  });
})();
```

And here is a little cleaner way. You declare the form URL at the top, the form fields, and for some of them, a function which will return a random value according to your needs.

To try this one out, save that script, and [try accessing this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQ9iT7isDU8IIbyg-wowB-9HGzyq-xu2NyzsOeG0j8fhytmA/viewform):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         GoogleForm Spammer
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Spam a Google Form
// @author       You
// @match        https://docs.google.com/forms/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var formUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQ9iT7isDU8IIbyg-wowB-9HGzyq-xu2NyzsOeG0j8fhytmA/viewform';
var formSchema = [
    {type: 'radio'},      // A
    {type: 'radio'},      // B
    {type: 'checkbox'},   // C
    {type: 'checkbox'},   // D
    {type: 'short_text', func: generateAnswerE },   // E
    {type: 'paragraph', func: generateParagraph },  // F
];

function generateAnswerE() {
  // Let's say we want a random number
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 16;
}

function generateParagraph() {
  // Just for the example
  return "Hello world";
}

(function() {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/forms/d') === 0) { // If we're on the form page
      submitRandomForm();
    } else if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/forms/u') === 0) { // If we're on the "submitted" page
      window.location.href = formUrl;
    }

    function submitRandomForm() {
      var formItems = document.querySelectorAll('.freebirdFormviewerViewItemsItemItem');

      for (var i = 0; i < formSchema.length; i++) {
        var field = formSchema[i],
            item  = formItems[i];
        switch(field.type) {
            case 'radio':
                var radios     = item.querySelectorAll(".appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupRadioButtonContainer"),
                    radioIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * radios.length);
                radios[radioIndex].click();
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
                var checkboxes    = item.querySelectorAll(".appsMaterialWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckbox"),
                    checkboxIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * checkboxes.length);
                checkboxes[checkboxIndex].click();
                break;
            case 'short_text':
                item.querySelector(".quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput").value = field.func();
                break;
            case 'paragraph':
                item.querySelector(".quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput").value = field.func();
                break;
        }
      }

      // Submit
      document.querySelector(".freebirdFormviewerViewCenteredContent .appsMaterialWizButtonPaperbuttonLabel").click();
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: It works perfectly, now i have to scale it to bigger form , where i have a lot of radios and checkboxes etc 
It should be easy, right ?

Comment: Doing it in a dirty way would be easy. Making it more maintainable/editable to work with any form would be nice, though. Giving it a try

Comment: @svennnx3 I added a second example, which will be easier to adapt to _any_ form (It only supports some field types though, as I couldn't get it to work with dropdowns yet)